# Change <li> list vertically to horozontally with 4 lines interval

Tags: html, css

I have a list with ul li like this

- Item line 1
- Item line 2
- Item line 3
- Item line 4
- Item line 5
- Item line 6
- Item line 7
- Item line 8
- Item line 9
- Item line 10
- Item line 11
- Item line 12

And I need to change to this, its possible only with CSS ?

```
Item line 1         Item line 5         Item line 9
Item line 2         Item line 6         Item line 10
Item line 3         Item line 7         Item line 11
Item line 4         Item line 8         Item line 12
```

Regards

Daniel

Comment: read about `column`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `columns` on the `<ul>`.

```css
ul {
  columns: 3;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
</ul>
```